# Programmatically access a SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How would I programmatically access a SharePoint document library from another machine? I want to recursively scan all the folders and generate a list of files with a certain custom property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the [List Data Retrieval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774413.aspx) web service. Example code using the service can be found on the [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774520(v=office.12).aspx) method page.

Answer (score 2):

Vinny is correct. I just wanted to elaborate a little on the next version of SharePoint, SharePoint 2010. There are several client based models for access that essentially wrap the web service calls. There is a managed .NET dll for Windorm/WPF applications, a library for use within websites that is JavaScript based and a Silverlight based implementation.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013(v=office.14).aspx) has links to more information on all three.